# Trouble displaying SVG file in dynamically created HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, icons

I'm trying to add a SVG image (that I downloaded from FontAwesome) to a button element that is created dynamically using JavaScript, but I'm having trouble getting the image to display. The image file is located in the svg folder in my project directory, and I'm using the following code to create the button and add the image to it:

```
const trashBtn = document.createElement('button');
trashBtn.classList.add('trash-icon');
const trashImg = document.createElement('img');
trashImg.src = 'svg/trash-icon.svg';
trashBtn.appendChild(trashImg);
item.appendChild(trashBtn);
```

but no image is displayed.

I've also tried using other file paths for the src attribute, such as `path/to/trash-icon.svg` and `file:///Users/myUserName/myProjectFolder/svg/trash-icon.svg`, but in these cases, I see an error image instead of the actual image.

I would appreciate any help in figuring out why the SVG file is not displaying in the img element.

```
<div class="main-container-2">
    <h3>Your Ingredients</h3>
    <p id="noItem">No selected ingredients</p>
    <ul id="urIngredients"></ul>
    <div class="link-ingredient hidden">
        <button><a href="./fridge.html" class="link-fridge">to my fridge</a></button>
        <button><a href="#" class="link-recipe">recipe</a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 'item' variable refers to an li element in #urIngredients that is dynamically created when the user selects an ingredient. The idea is to dynamically create a button that displays an SVG trash can icon, and the button should appear on each dynamically created list item.

**I actually just have found a solution in another way adding background-img to the button instead of adding img in the button but I am still curious about why the previous approach did not work.**